# Node.js and ExpressJS body-parser package retrieve data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, body-parser

OK first time user of Node, and I am trying to send data to `backend/index.js`

**Requirements**

- Post data to back-end node
- Retrieve posted data and store values as variables

**Whats the problem**

The post is 200 success, that works.

however when I navigate to  :

> http://localhost:8080/backend/index

I get :

> Cannot GET /backend/index

Where am I going wrong ?

**Here is my front end post post**

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/backend/index.js",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "id": "1223",
    "token": "223",
    "geo": "ee"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I am trying to retrieve this data from and store as variable in the back end node.

**backend/index.js**

```
// grab the packages we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// routes will go here

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

// POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
// parameters sent with
app.post('/backend/index', function(req, res) {
    var user_id = req.body.id;
    var token = req.body.token;
    var geo = req.body.geo;

    res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ' + geo);
});
```

**UPDATE using screen shots** 
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't specify GET method, you can do like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('do something 1');
});

app.get('/backend/index', function(req, res) {
    res.send('do something 2');
});
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you Post Api  and you can not get result without parameter.
Your  Post Api will not give output until you hit only url on web browser, so need postman for Post Api.

[image]

Now you get Output without any problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes ive used a rest client (Insomnia) to post the data, ill try again. thanks

Comment: use this
 var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});